# Setting privacy parameter for pictures

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am posting with my own android app pictures and descriptions to my own timeline. So now I want to restrict the access to this pictures to dedicated friendlists.

Can anyone post an example how to do this? I know that I have to add the privacy parameters during the picture upload to my request but I cant find any example for java and android in the web

So I need an example for giving acces to all my friends and how to give access to two or three of my friendlists

Regards

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying and searching I found the solution for my own problem. You need to add the following parameters during the upload of the picture

Example:

Bundle params = new Bundle();

String myPrivacy = "{\"value\":\"CUSTOM\" , \"allow\": \"10000000000\" , \"deny\": \"100000000000\" }";

params.putString("privacy", myPrivacy);

Regards

Michael